# Magento 2 - Custom style _listings.less not working

Tags: magento, less, magento2

We are using Porto theme. We have our product list with the style:

```
<div class="product details product-item-details"> code </div>
```

We checked the porto .less which corresponds to:

> app\design\frontend\Smartwave\porto\Magento_Catalog\web\css\source\module_listings.less

Where the part where we have the style:

```
.products-list {
.product {
    &-item {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px 0;

        &-info {
            display: table-row;
            text-align: left;

            &:after {
                display: table;
                content: '';
                clear: both;
            }                
        }
        &-photo {
            width: 20%;
            display: block;
            float: left;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        &-details {
            display: block;
            width: 80%;
            padding: 0 0 20px 20px;
            float: left;

            .actions-primary {
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .actions-secondary {
                margin-left: 2px;
            }
        }
        &-name {
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 1;
            margin: 10px 0;
        }
        .product-reviews-summary {
            background: none;
        }
    }
}
.product-image-wrapper {
    &:extend(.abs-reset-image-wrapper all);
}
```

}

I have overwritten the file:

> app\design\frontend\Smartwave\porto_customTheme\web\css\source\module_listings.less

And the part I want to change is this one:

```
& when (@media-common = true) {

  .products-list {
    .product {
      &-item {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px 0;
        &-details {
          display: block;
          width: 100%;
          padding: 0 0 20px 20px;
          float: left;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically the issue I have is that the products show with width: 80% instead of width 100%:

80%:
[image]

100%:
[image]

I run these commands:

```
rm -rf pub/static/*;
php bin/magento setup:upgrade;
php bin/magento setup:di:compile;
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ca_ES;
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy es_ES;
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy;
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the code out of @media and try.